# Problems booting in 5.19.0-45-generic kernel

Tags: boot

A previous post stated similar, I also did as he did - booted into an earlier kernal.
When I booted originally I got the folloeing on my screen and thats it.
Remapped IO_APIC
[        0.000000]  CPU: PID: 0 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 5.19.0-45-generic #46~22.04.1-Ubuntu
[        0.000000] Hardware name: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. AX370-Gaming K5/AX370-Gamming K5-CF, BIOS F3 06/16/2017
[        0.000000] Call Trace:
[        0.000000]  
[        0.000000]  show_stack+0x52/0x69
[        0.000000]  dump_stack_lvl+0x49/0x6d
[        0.000000]  dump_stack+0x20/0x18
[        0.000000]  panic+0x162/0x316
[        0.000000]  panic_if_irq_remap.cold+0x9/0x9
[        0.000000]  check_timer+0x226/0x561
[        0.000000]  ? radix_tree_lookup+0xd/0x20
[        0.000000]  setup_IO_APIC+0x1c6/0x1e9
[        0.000000]  apic_intr_mode_init+0xfd/0x113
[        0.000000]  x86_late_time_init+0x24/0x4e4
[        0.000000]  start_kernal+0x417/0x4e4
[        0.000000]  x86_64_start_reservations+0x24/0x2c
[        0.000000]  x86_64_start_kernal+0xee/0x103
[        0.000000]  secondary_startup_64_no_verify+0xe5/0xeb
[        0.000000]  
[        0.000000] ---[ end Kernal panic – not syncing: timer dosen’t work through Interrupt-remapped IO-APIC ]---

My system is now running on the older kernel. I hope this is helpfull to others.
Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

with the initialerrors, I thought I may have an hardware problem. After some basic diagnostics , I eventually updated to the latest Kernel version - 6.3.7, (at time of writing). This if done incorrectly could cause potentially more problems. Here is a link to a site that explains in detail how to go about doing this.

https://linux.how2shout.com/how-to-change-default-kernel-in ubuntu-22-04-20-04-lts/

Hope this helps, thanks all.